# how to do $filter with more then one expression and comparator in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, filter

i want to filter in angular controller with two expression and two comparator function my code with loop is working fine

```
angular.forEach(vm.campaignData, function (value) {
                if (value.startTime < today && value.endTime > today) {
                    vm.campaignFilteredData.push(value);
                }
            });
```

but i want with $filter but it is not working

```
vm.campaignFilteredData =$filter('filter')(vm.campaignData, {startTime : today , endTime: today} ,
            function(actual, expected ) { return actual < expected;},function(actual, expected ) { return actual > expected;});
```

my data is like this

[{

```
"name": "Levis Marketing Event Vadodra Himalaya Mall",
"tenantId": 1,
"locationId": 5,
"createdByName": "sg_area_manager",
"startTime": 1462300200000,
"endTime": 1462473000000,
"description": "This event for Marketing Levis Vadodra Himalaya Mall",
"metricIds": [],
"comparisionStartTs": 0,
"comparisionEndTs": 0
```

},
  {

```
"name": "Levis Festival Event Vadodra Himalaya Mall",
"tenantId": 1,
"locationId": 5,
"createdByName": "sg_area_manager",
"startTime": 1462300200000,
"endTime": 1462473000000,
"description": "This event for Festival Levis Vadodra Himalaya Mall",
"metricIds": [],
"comparisionStartTs": 0,
"comparisionEndTs": 0
```

}]

Comment: Can you reproduce with some data in JSFiddle or Plunker??

Comment: hi @RomeshJain my other filter work perfect like this ==>vm.campaignFilteredData =$filter('filter')(vm.campaignData, {startTime : today} , function(actual, expected) { return actual > expected;});

Comment: Ok! But it will be helpful if you provide with data and your which is not working. Also mention that what is expected result.

Answer (score 1):

Not the ideal solution, but it gets the job done. Better create your own angular filter though.

https://jsfiddle.net/ygL8rnb8/

```
 vm.campaignFilteredData = $filter('filter')(vm.campaignData,
      function(value) {
        if (value.startTime < today && value.endTime > today) {
          return true;
        }
      }
    );
```